# Heroku - "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." though it exists on localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I tried almost every solution from the previous questions, but there is no which applies to my problem. Basically, my app works on localhost:3000 but does not on Heroku. I generated scaffold User name:string email:string. Git commited and pushed to Heroku, it states that everythings went ok. However, on the page http://appofmine.herokuapp.com/ I get 404.

**heroku logs:**

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=appofmine.herokuapp.com request_id=e39fb228-d587-4d18-8395-2405eec3a59d fwd="85.202.153.28" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=228
```

**routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  root "users#index"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most probably happening because you did not run the migrations on heroku, so, the database tables are not created yet and hence you get this error. This is a very common mistake that people do while deploying their application to heroku.

Make sure you migrate the database on heroku before accessing the page:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much again, you made my day :D